# Facebook name in user profile

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I just implemented the email login (firebase) in my app, where the user can add manually the name in a textfield and when arrive in the profile page find the name (label) just entered in the first viewController (this is part of the code of profileViewController)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.user = Auth.auth().currentUser

    self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(self.user!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        self.name.text = snapshotValue?["name"] as? String
        self.handle.text = snapshotValue?["handle"] as? String

        if(snapshotValue?["about"] != nil){
            self.usernameField.text = snapshotValue?["about"] as? String
        }

        if(snapshotValue?["profile_pic"] != nil){
            let databaseProfilePic = snapshotValue!["profile_pic"] as! String

            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: databaseProfilePic)!)

            self.setProfilePicture(imageView: self.ProfilePicture,imageToSet:UIImage(data:data!)!)
        }
        self.imageLoader.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

Different with the Facebook login is that the user do not enter any data but i take this

```
let graphRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name,email, picture.type(large)"])
```

from the FBSDK, so how i can use these parameters to make that when a user logged with Facebook and come in the profile page find his name (that is the fb profile name)? I'm trying to find a solution around the net but i have not found anything.

Comment: Firebase is giving login with facebook accounts so please use it. 
Here is the link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login

Comment: instead of checking if an optional is nil and then force unwrapping + force casting it, use optional binding (`if let` or `guard let`) and safe casting. Moreover, using `try?` and then force unwrapping the result makes no sense, if an error would be thrown, you will still get a runtime exception, but instead of seeing the actual cause for it, you will only see the force unwrapping nil error...

Comment: @JitendraModi i used it, i just implemented the Facebook login with firebase, the only thing i need is how my label name in the profileViewController take the Facebook user name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user account is created and logged in via the following method :

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

Auth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential)
```

You should be able to access the user basic profile information using :

```
Auth.auth()?.currentUser
```

For example, to get the user name, you would do :

```
guard let currentUser = Auth.auth()?.currentUser else {
   return
}

userNameLabel.text = currentUser.displayName
```

You could also write all the user data in your database when you first create the user account via the signIn method like so :

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

// Create and sign in the user account using the Facebook access token.

Auth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (currentUser, error) in         

     guard error == nil else {
         return
     }

     // Create an array of user data using authenticationData.

     let currentUserData: [String: String] = ["name" : authenticationData.providerData["displayName"], 
     "email": authenticationData.providerData["email"] ]

     // Write user data in the database.

     usersRef.updateChildValues(currentUserData, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

     guard error == nil else {
         return
     }

     // ...Segue to your home controller here

}
```

And then use the `observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` on the `usersRef` to read your user profile data.

Comment: Cool I'm glad to hear that it works @bero ! Have a nice day :)